# What's the most compact Groovy statement that tests that all items in a list may be cast to long?

Tags: groovy

I'm looking for a succinct expression for evaluating whether or not all the items in a list are either Longs or may be converted to Longs.  I'm looking for a compact expression, but I prefer readability over mere [code golf](http://codegolf.com/).

Examples:

```
assert expr([1,2,'3'])
assert expr([1,'fish',3]) == false
assert expr([null]) == false
assert expr([' ', 17]) == false
```

Comment: Groovy will successfully convert all above arrays into `long` arrays. e.g. `[null] as long[]` is `[null]` and `[' ', 17] as long[]` is `[32,17]` (converted to ascii value).. Do you mean to test numeric-ness?

Comment: @paislee That's pretty different than what I took the question to be asking for, since `[1, 'fish', 3]` would throw an exception, which is different than a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For readability, I would do something like:

```
def canBeLongs(things) {
    things.every { 
        try { Long.valueOf(it); true } 
        catch (e) { false }
    }
}

assert canBeLongs([1,2,'3'])
assert !canBeLongs([1,'fish',3])
assert !canBeLongs([null])
assert !canBeLongs([' ', 17])
```

Just for the lulz, this other solution is horrible, but it's very succinct and covers all the test cases:

```
def f(l) { l.join() ==~ /[0-9]*/ }

assert f([1,2,'3'])
assert !f([1,'fish',3])
assert !f([null])
assert !f([' ', 17])
```

Comment: +1 really nice answer...  managed to get it a [tiny bit shorter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932300/6509) too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The shortest I can get on the first go is:

```
def expr = { a ->
  a.inject([]) { c, v -> 
    c << { try{ Long.valueOf(it); true } catch(e){ false } }( v )
  }.every()
}
```

#### Edit

@epidemian has the best answer, which can be made shorter by moving the try outside the loop

```
def canBeLongs(things) {
  try { things.every { Long.valueOf(it) } }
  catch(e) { false }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but careful with the zero! As it stands, `canBeLongs([0])` yields false. As the return value of `Long.valueOf(it)` is not important, you may change the `every` with a `each` and do something like: `try { things.each { Long.valueOf(it) }; true } catch(e) { false }`

Comment: Or, just for kicks, `try { things.each { Long.valueOf(it) | 1 } } catch(e) { false }` =D

Comment: Or, indeed: `try { !things*.toLong().any { it == null } } catch(e) { false }`, but it's the same length ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There's actually a built in `String.isLong()` method from Groovy, so another (terrible) answer that is succinct is:

```
def canBeLongs(things) { things.every{ "$it".long } }

assert canBeLongs([1,2,'3'])
assert canBeLongs([1,'fish',3]) == false
assert canBeLongs([null]) == false
assert canBeLongs([' ', 17]) == false
```

I only include it because it's so short.

Comment: Maybe it's a newer Groovy function, because I just copied my testing code right from GroovyConsole.  `getLong` will give you false negatives, because it will return false for any `0` values, like `"0"`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I'm not on 1.8 yet.

Comment: Actually, I just checked, the `isLong` method [has been around since groovy 1.5](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isLong%28%29), so it should still work.  Alternatively, `String.valueOf(it).long` might work

Comment: Sorry.  I meant to write "$it".isLong() in my comment above.  Force of habit.  I still can't explain why "$it".long didn't compile, but no big deal.  Thanks for your assistance.